# Mac kernel driver link error

Tags: macos, kernel

I have upgraded my driver from Xcode-4.3 SDK to Xcode-7.1 SDK, when I fix some deprecated API error in usb driver, there comes an link error about can not find cpp_kext lib, what is this lib used for? I wonder if it is the root cause, since this driver has been used for a while, just occurred this error when I upgraded SDK.

Comment: well resolved, I found the libcpp_kext is for i386 arch, when moving to Xcode7, it will only support x86_64, so get rid of that link path, then will go right